# How to use embedded Object in mongoose Schemas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have Schema:

```
var someSchema = new Schema({
    data: {
        nickname: {type: String},
        id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        message: { type: String},
    },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

But when I am trying to use it:

```
some.collection.insert({data.nickname: nickname, data.message: message,}, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) {
      console.log("Something wrong !");
  }
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

I have an error: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token .**

How to insert data to my Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same nested object syntax when defining the document to insert:

```
some.collection.insert({data: {nickname: nickname, message: message}}, function(err, doc) {
  if (err) {
      console.log("Something wrong !");
  }
  res.redirect('/');
});
```